# Splitting python code into different files

Tags: python, module

I am a beginner in Python, and I am trying to learn by making a simple game. I started by having everything in one big file (let's call it `main.py`), but it is getting to the point where it has so many classes and functions that I would like to split this code into more manageable components.

I have some experience with LaTeX (although certainly not an expert either) and, in LaTeX there is a function called \input which allows one to write part of the code in a different file. For example, if I have files `main.tex` and `sub.tex` which look like:

main.tex:

```
Some code here.
\input{sub}
Lastly, some other stuff.
```

and
sub.tex:

```
Some more code here
```

then, when I execute `main.tex`, it will execute:

```
Some code here.
Some more code here
Lastly, some other stuff.
```

I wonder, is there a similar thing in Python?

---

*Note 1*: From what I have seen, the most commonly suggested way to go about splitting your code is to use modules. I have found this a bit uncomfortable for a few reasons, which I will list below (of course, I understand that I find them uncomfortable because I am a inexperienced, and not because this is the wrong way to do things).
Reasons why I find modules uncomfortable:

1. My `main.py` file imports some other modules, like Pygame, which need to be imported into all the new modules I create. If for some reason I wanted to import a new module into `main.py` later in the process I would then need to import it on every other module I create.
2. My `main.py` file has some global variables that are used in the different classes; for example, I have a global variable `CITY_SIZE` that controls the size of all `City` instances on the screen. Naturally, `CITY_SIZE` is used in the definition of the class `City`. If I were to move the class `City` to a module `classes.py`, then I need to define `CITY_SIZE` on `classes.py` as well, and if I ever wanted to change the value of `CITY_SIZE` I would need to change its value on `classes.py` as well.
3. Again, suppose that I add a `classes.py` module where I store all my classes, like `City`. Then in `main.py` I need to write `classes.City` in my code instead of `City`. I understand this can be overcome by using `from classes import City` but then I need to add a line of code every time I add a new class to `classes.py`.

*Note 2*: I would very much appreciate any comments about how to use modules comfortably in Python, but please note that because this is not my question I would not be able to accept those as valid answers (but, again, they would be appreciated!).

Comment: The idea is that you will split your big file into smaller, more focused, chunks of code. The code in each file should be closely related. Then when you read the individual files they should be easier to understand because they are doing less work. For example you could try and put everything to do with presentation in one file, how things are represented on screen could be separated from the game logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of your modules in the same directory, you can simply use:

```py
import <name of submodule without .py>
```

For example, if a submodule file was named `sub.py`, you would import it like this:

```py
import sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I am afraid I am looking for something a bit different. For example, if ```sub.py``` is ```print(n)``` and ```main.tex``` is ```n = 5, import sub``` then we get an error.

Comment: But if sub.py contains `def printy(x):`, then you can call `sub.printy(n)` from main.py. You would typically import functions or classes at the top of main.py, and use them. Rather than importing in-line like that.